# Why isn’t this drill bit going any further?

Tags: wood, drill, stuck

We’re trying to build a banister. This piece of wood would be the end piece. The tip of the drill barely goes into the wood before it gets stuck. We just tried charging the battery, but that wasn’t the fix.

Any insight would be great.

[image]

Comment: is the drill turning in the correct direction?

Comment: I will admit to having the driver running in reverse more than once... Wondered why my drywall screws wouldn't go in to fresh construction lumber.

Comment: You should be able to push through that soft wood even in _reverse_ with a sharp bit. Is the white powder on the bit concrete or gypsum?

Comment: Not easy to see from such a distant shot, but Photoshop tells me that bit has bitten off more than it can chew, or been used on concrete. The 'sharp' edges… aren't. It's a dead parrot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Rs0.png

Comment: By struck, you mean the bit is not drilling into the wood, or the bit gets struck and stops turning?

Comment: @crip659 - 'stuck' not 'struck'. OP's bit shows clear signs they've been using it to go through wood, then 'cement-based' substrate. It's had enough, kicked the bucket, shuffled off its mortal coil, run down the curtain & joined the choir bleedin' invisible. It's an ex-drill-bit. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin  The hole size suggests the smaller bit between the box and the hammer.  Not sure which bit OP is having trouble with.

Comment: @crip659 - there's zero discernible detail on that other bit. OP is going to have to clarify.

Comment: Is that even a wood bit? Tip looks very flat, like a masonry bit. Or it's just broken off.

Comment: If your bit does get stuck (i.e. stops turning because it's gotten jammed on something), is it possible this is re-used wood and there's an old nail or nail remnant stuck in the end of the 2x4 that you're hitting with your bit?